# Clustered Index And Non Culstered Index In IBM Db2

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, primary-key

Am little confused with **clustered index** and **non clustered index**.
is any differences in **MySQL** and **DB2** regarding clustered Indexing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In DB2, any single index on a table can be designated as the table's cluster*ing* index.  The index is a normal b-tree index, no different (physically) than any other index other than the fact that it's been identified as the clustering index.  The index has a series of index keys, and each index key has a list of RIDs (row IDs) that point to the physical location of the data for each row that matches the index key.

If you reorganize the table (using the `REORG TABLE` utility) DB2 will physically arrange the table's data (which is separate from the index's data) in the same physical order as the clustering index. DB2 will attempt to maintain the physical clustering order as new rows are inserted into the table (and you can help it by choosing an appropriate value for table's `PCTFREE` attribute), but over time the cluster ratio may decrease and you may need to reorganize the table again.

Compare this with MySQL, where with InnoDB, the table's data is stored in the primary key index's structure.  So, unlike DB2 where the index has the key columns and then a list of RIDs, the primary key index stores the entire row – there is no separate storage object holding the table's data.  This is why it's called a cluster*ed* index rather than a cluster*ing* index.  This massively increases the size of the physical index, making it significantly harder to ensure that it will remain cached in memory.

Secondary indexes in InnoDB store the index key and the primary key columns for the rows (rather than a RID) – this could be inefficient if the primary key is made up of many columns.

`<soapbox>`

Using the primary key (or any unique key) for "clustering" is *ridiculous*. The entire point of clustering it to maintain locality of *related* data. InnoDB is not alone here - Microsoft SQL Server does this as well.

Take, for example, a transaction table.  The primary key for this table may be `transaction_id`.  With InnoDB, this is the clustered index.  However, the likelihood that one transaction ID is related to the next transaction ID is pretty low.

`account_id` would make a much better clustering key precisely **because it is not unique**.  If I'm looking for all transactions for a particular `account_id`, having all of those rows on a single physical page makes a lot of sense and greatly will reduce the amount of I/O necessary to find all of those rows.

If the table's data is stored as part of the primary key's structure (i.e. on `transaction_id`), then you'll likely be reading pages from **all over the index** just to find all of the transactions for a single account.

You may argue that storing all of the data as part of the primary key is a performance benefit (i.e., 1 I/O to get any particular row), but this also means that caching the index has just become a lot harder because it will be much bigger.  "In memory" may be *de rigueur*, but if you need as much RAM as the size of your database to maintain performance that's useful only up to a point.

`</soapbox>`

Comment: I would like to add that, as far as I know, DB2 implements *clustering* indexes, but not *clustered* indexes.